# JSON.parse error when using multilayered error

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, object

I get the following error when trying to run JSON.Parse

```
{"documents": [{"documentId": "1","fileExtension": "pdf","name": "Top_Level_Agreement.pdf"}]},{"Email Subject":"DocuSign-Top Level Agreement"},{"Envelope Reciepients":[{"carbonCopies":[{"carbonCopy1":[{"email":"zabie@toplevelstaging.com","name":"Zabie Sahial","recipientId":"2"}]{"signers":[+
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 93
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object. (/home/toplevelstaging/TopLevel

Here is my code

```
  var Envelope_Definition = [];
    Envelope_Definition[0] = '{"documents": ['+
    '{"documentId": "1","fileExtension": "pdf","name": "Top_Level_Agreement.pdf"}]}';
    Envelope_Definition[1] = '{"Email Subject":"DocuSign-Top Level Agreement"}';
    Envelope_Definition[2] = '{"Envelope Reciepients":['+
        '{"carbonCopies":['+
            '{"carbonCopy1":['+
                '{"email":"zabie@toplevelstaging.com","name":"Zabie Sahial","recipientId":"2"}]'+
        '{"signers":[+'
            '{"signer1":['+
                '{"EnvelopeTabs":['+
                    '{""}]"}]}]}}]}';


    data = JSON.parse(Envelope_Definition);
    console.log(data);
```

Comment: Why would you do that instead of just using ordinary JavaScript object literals?

Comment: Using this to create a JSON object that i need to input dynamic info into before submitting

Comment: There's absolutely not point in building a JSON string in JavaScript in preparation for calling `JSON.parse()`. Just build an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is

```
var data = {"documents": [
  {"documentId": "1","fileExtension": "pdf","name": "Top_Level_Agreement.pdf"}]},
  {"Email Subject":"DocuSign-Top Level Agreement"},
  {"Envelope Reciepients":[
    {"carbonCopies":[{"email":"zabie@toplevelstaging.com","name":"Zabie Sahial","recipientId":"2"}],
    {"signers":[{"signer1":[{"EnvelopeTabs":[{}]}]}]}}]};
```

(or something like that). JavaScript **natively** supports object definition via a literal syntax. That's where JSON comes from; that's why it's called "JavaScript Object Notation".

Comment: Makes sense, how would I update the envelopetabs data in this object after creating

Comment: @LeoColeman- check out this resource on working with objects.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects